# Django url template tage and variable values with dot (.)

Tags: django, url, templates, tags

why doesn't {% url myVar %} where myVar = 'jack.johnson' doesn't work ?

The view is fine, the urls.py is:
url(r'^(?P[A-Za-z0-9-._]+)/$', overview, name='user_profile'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys, sorry. I found my mistake and the example I gave was misleading.
Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Because the URL name is 'user_profile', not 'jack.johnson'.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that you're using at least Django 1.0 (named url patterns didn't exist before then), re-read the Django doc on [Naming URL Patterns](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), then try

```
{% url user_profile myVar %}
```